# Como converter o formato de uma data em JavaScript para ISO 8601?

Tags: javascript, data, datepicker

Tenho aqui um código que efetua uma operação em JavaScript. Ele determina a data máxima de nascimento que pode ser inserida num formulário. A regra é que só pode se cadastrar quem tem 18 anos e mais.

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var dtMax = new Date(year - 18, month, day);
```

Como passar essa data de `Wed May 03 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` para `2000-05-03` - ISO 8601?

O método `toISOString()` deveria retornar o valor desejado. Esse valor será usado para limitar a data máxima de um [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Nota: para deixar clara a pergunta, o objetivo final pode ser alcançado com esse código:

```
var yearMax = dtMax.getFullYear();
var monthMax = dtMax.getMonth();
var dayMax = dtMax.getDate();
var strMax = yearMax+"-"+monthMax+"-"+dayMax;
```

Quero saber se tem alguma maneira mais direta.

Aqui o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vewm6uk/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) retorna uma string contendo tanto a data quanto a hora, então uma alternativa seria simplesmente pegar a parte que interessa, usando [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 18);
console.log(d.toISOString().substr(0, 10));
```

---

Usar [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/296086/112052), nem sempre vai funcionar, pois este método usa o *locale* ("idioma") que está configurado no browser para saber qual formato usar.

E dependendo do *locale*, nem sempre o formato será "dia/mês/ano". Para browsers configurado com inglês americano, por exemplo, a data é retornada no formato "mês/dia/ano", e sem o zero à esquerda para valores menores que 10 (ou seja, se a data for 1 de março de 2000, o resultado será `2000-1-3`). Outros locales retornam os campos em outra ordem (como "ano/mês/dia"), enquanto outros usam caracteres diferentes da barra como separadores. Ou seja, o uso deste método não garante que o resultado final será o correto.

Uma opção é forçar um *locale* que possui o formato pretendido:

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 18);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR').split("/").reverse().join("-"));
```

O *locale* `pt-BR` possui o formato de data "dia/mês/ano" com os valores menores que 10 preenchidos com um zero à esquerda, o que garante que este método funcionará.

Porém, há ainda algumas situações em que isso pode falhar. Se o browser não tiver o *locale* `pt-BR` instalado, ele acaba usando o *default*. Ou também pode acontecer - embora eu ache que seja um pouco mais raro - de o formato correspondente ao *locale* mudar (já que ele é predefinido e você não tem controle sobre o mesmo - veja mais sobre isso [na parte final desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408649/112052)).

Outro detalhe é que `toISOString()` retorna a data/hora em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), enquanto `toLocaleDateString()` retorna a data de acordo com o timezone configurado no browser (ou seja, dependendo do timezone configurado e da hora do dia em que o código roda, estes métodos podem retornar uma data diferente). Mas se quiser, é possível fazer com que `toLocaleDateString()` retorne a data em UTC:

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 18);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', { timeZone: "UTC" }).split("/").reverse().join("-"));
```

Enfim, estas são as opções que a API nativa de datas do JavaScript nos dá, então escolha o que achar melhor.

---

Ainda há outro problema no código acima. Caso a data seja 29 de fevereiro:

```js
// lembrando que em JavaScript janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc
let d = new Date(2016, 1, 29); // 29/02/2016
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 18);
console.log(d.toISOString().substr(0, 10)); // 1998-03-01
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR').split("/").reverse().join("-")); // 1998-03-01
```

Ao subtrair 18 anos de 29/02/2016, o resultado é 1 de março de 1998. Mas alguém que nasceu em 01/03/1998 ainda não tem 18 anos em 29/02/2016 (ainda falta um dia para o aniversário), então esta não deveria uma data válida para ser mostrada no seu formulário (uma solução seria mostrar 28/02/1998). Infelizmente o JavaScript não possui uma forma automática de fazer esse ajuste, então este é um caso em que você deve verificar manualmente.

---

### Moment.js

Uma alternativa à API nativa é a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Com ela fica bem fácil fazer o que você precisa:

```js
let d = moment(); // data atual
d.subtract(18, 'years'); // menos 18 anos
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // mostrar no formato ano-mês-dia
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Inclusive para o caso de 29 de fevereiro, ela já faz o ajuste automaticamente:

```js
let d = moment([2016, 1, 29]); // 29/02/2016
d.subtract(18, 'years'); // menos 18 anos
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // 1998-02-28
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se diminuir uma linha no código seja mais direto :D

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear( d.getFullYear() - 18 );
var newdate = (d.toLocaleDateString()).split("/").reverse().join("-");
console.log(newdate);
```

Comment: Esse reverse funssiona bem com split.

Comment: Tem: `. = .; console.log(.);`

Comment: aha.. to brincando... cara, acho que não tem como reduzir mais não... já tá bom demais