# Formatação da Data/Hora incorreta NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN:NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, data

O Campo `DateTime` que retorna do Banco está formatada como `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, porèm quando começa a fazer o looping ($each) conofrme o código abaixo a formatação muda para: "/Date(1566322265000)/".

Criei essa função para formatar a Data/Hora em dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss, porém me retorna errada, assim: **NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN:NaN**

Exemplo: 
Obs.: Coloquei somente o código relevante.

```
var data = "/Date(1566322265000)/";

$.each(response.listarLoginLogout, function (index, item) {

var _Data = FormatarDataddMMyyyyhrmmss(item.DATA);
console.log("Resultado: " + _Data);



});

function FormatarDataddMMyyyyhrmmss(data) {
    var dataFormatada = "";
    if (data != null) {
        var _dtAux = /\/Date\((\d+).*\)\//.exec(data);
        var _dtIni = new Date(parseInt(_dtAux[1]));
        var dtMilissegundos = new Date(_dtIni.toLocaleString());
        var dd = dtMilissegundos.getDate();
        var MM = dtMilissegundos.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = dtMilissegundos.getFullYear();
        var hh = dtMilissegundos.getHours();
        var mm = dtMilissegundos.getMinutes();
        var ss = dtMilissegundos.getSeconds();
        if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd; };
        if (MM < 10) { MM = '0' + MM; };
        if (hh < 10) { hh = '0' + hh; };
        if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm; };
        if (ss < 10) { ss = '0' + ss; };
        dataFormatada = dd + "/" + MM + "/" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    }
    return dataFormatada;
};
```

Comment: Coisas como `new Date("xxxx").getMonth()` produzem `NaN` como resultado. Assim sendo, o que há na sua variável `response.listarLoginLogout`, em especial no campo `DATA` disso?

Comment: Usar `/\/Date\((\d+).*\)\//.exec(data)` não parece ser uma boa ideia sob o ponto de vista de segurança.

Comment: NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN:NaN batmaaaan

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sempre que vejo um monte de NaN eu lembro disso: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Bom dia! Obrigado @Victor Stafusa pelas observações eu resolvi o problema conforme as sugestões abaixo e vou marcar como post respondido, no entanto respondendo sua pergunta dentro do campo `DATA` tem a seguinte string: `"/Date(1566322265000)/"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução bem simples seria assim, criando um objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) com o comando [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```js
var data = eval("/Date(1566322265000)/".replace('/','new ').replace('/',''));
//Somente a data
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));
//Somente a hora
console.log(data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR'));
//A data e a hora
console.log(data.toLocaleString('pt-BR'));
```

poderia até ser criado uma função para facilitar isso:

```js
// example: '/Date(1566322265000)/'

function data_parse_br(value) {
  const data = eval(value.replace('/', 'new ').replace('/', ''));
  //return data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR') + ' ' +  data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR')
  //ou
  return data.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
}

console.log(data_parse_br('/Date(1566322265000)/'));
```

Talvez uma opção que eu particularmente gosto é com [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js) da seguinte forma:

```js
function date_parse_br(value, format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss') {
  moment.locale('pt-br');
  return moment(value).format(format);
}

console.log(date_parse_br('/Date(1566322265000)/'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

pelo fator praticidade, o [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js) faz as conversões necessárias.

Comment: Se não me engano, `toLocaleString('pt-BR')` já formata a data e a hora com um espaço separando-os, então não precisaria usar `toLocaleDateString` concatenado com `toLocaleTimeString`

Comment: @hkotsubo esse fator de não precisaria torna a resposta de certo modo pobre, concordo que um fator adicional colocando um método que resolva a formatação de data e hora de uma vez é legal, mas, informar que tem a opção de ter as informações separados também é um bom negócio. Agradeço e já foi adicionado as duas formas. ***Eu acho também que não merece voto negativo***.

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o negativo

Comment: Bom dia! @Vigilio Novic gostei muita da sugestão do uso do moment.js, já implementei e os Relatórios já estão em produção (10 Relatórios) e todos utilizam essa moment.js. Agradeço !

Answer (score 4):

Você pode simplificar bastante o seu *script*. Pode fazer assim:

```js
const test = '/Date(1566322265000)/';

function formatDate(dateString) {
  const [, ms] = dateString.match(/\((\d+)\)\/$/);
  const instance = new Date(parseInt(ms, 10));

  // Uma pequena função que formata a parte da data automaticamente, somando
  // `1` ao valor retornado, caso necessário.
  const get = (method, sum = false) =>
    (instance[method]() + (sum ? 1 : 0)).toString().padStart(2, '0');

  const DD = get('getDate');
  const MM = get('getMonth', true);
  const YY = get('getFullYear');
  const hh = get('getHours');
  const mm = get('getMinutes');
  const ss = get('getSeconds');

  return `${DD}/${MM}/${YY} ${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`;
}

console.log(formatDate(test));
```

Para facilitar no *padding* das partes da data, criei uma função auxiliar chamada `get`, que faz uso do método [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Comment: Bom dia ! @Luz Felipe ajudou muito para o meu conhecimento. Obrigado! Funciona também !

Answer (score 4):

Também da para fazer assim:

```js
var data = "/Date(1566322265000)/";


console.log("Data: " + (new Date(parseInt(data.replace(/\D/g,'')))).toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));
```

Comment: Obrigado ! @Augusto Vasques é uma opção ! Valeu !!

Answer (score 4):

As outras respostas já deram soluções para obter o formato da data, mas acho que vale uma explicação sobre qual foi o erro do seu código.

Primeiro você extrai o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) usando regex, e cria a data. Até aqui tudo bem:

```js
var data = "/Date(1566322265000)/";
var _dtAux = /\/Date\((\d+).*\)\//.exec(data);
var _dtIni = new Date(parseInt(_dtAux[1]));
```

No caso, o timestamp `1566322265000` corresponde a "20 de agosto de 2019, às 14:31:05, no Horário de Brasília". É o que `_dtIni` contém: uma data correspondente a este instante específico.

Mas aí você usa [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), que retorna a data em um formato específico (como uma string), e cria outra data usando esta string:

```
var dtMilissegundos = new Date(_dtIni.toLocaleString());
```

Este é o ponto que está errado.

Primeiro que, ao chamar [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) sem parâmetros, é usado um formato correspondente ao *locale* que estiver configurado no browser (que, se não me engano, depende das configurações de idioma do mesmo).

Então o primeiro ponto é que a string que será gerada por este método pode não ser a mesma para todos os clientes, já que alguns locales usam "dia/mês/ano", outros (como o inglês `en-US`) usam "mês/dia/ano", outros usam "ano/mês/dia", etc. E conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052), o único formato padronizado que o construtor de `Date` reconhece e funciona da mesma maneira em todos os browsers é o [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ("ano-mês-dia**T**hora:minuto:segundo" - repare na letra `T` entre a data e o horário), e qualquer formato que não seja esse *poderá* ter um comportamento diferente, que varia conforme o browser.

Por exemplo, no meu browser (Chrome, configurado com o *locale* `pt-BR` - português do Brasil), `toLocaleString()` retorna a string `"20/08/2019 14:31:05"`. E ao fazer `new Date("20/08/2019 14:31:05")`, o resultado é `Invalid Date` (que o *snippet* abaixo pode mostrar como `null`). Isso ocorre porque, quando esse formato é usado, a implementação do Chrome assume que o formato é "**mês**/dia/ano hora:minuto:segundo":

```js
// o Chrome entende que esse formato é mês/dia/ano hora:minuto:segundo
console.log(new Date("11/08/2019 14:31:05")); // 8 de novembro
console.log(new Date("20/08/2019 14:31:05")); // data inválida, pois o mês é 20
```

E como no segundo caso, o mês é 20, a data é inválida. E ao tentar chamar qualquer método desta data inválida (como [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), etc), o resultado é `NaN`.

Provavelmente o seu browser está configurado com um *locale* que produz um formato diferente do ISO 8601, e que também causa um erro parecido.

---

Dito isso, você poderia ter parado na criação de `_dtIni`. Ela já é uma data correspondente ao timestamp que você obteve com a regex (ou seja, já é o que você precisa), não há motivo nenhum para criar outra data derivada desta. Depois bastava usar `_dtIni.getDate()`, `_dtIni.getMonth()`, etc, para obter os valores corretos.

Como alternativa às outras respostas, para este formato específico você pode usar `toLocaleString('pt-BR')`:

```js
let data = "/Date(1566322265000)/";
let m = data.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
if (m) {
    let d = new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
    console.log(d.toLocaleString('pt-BR')); // 20/08/2019 14:31:05
}
```

Repare também que removi o `.*` da regex: o `\d+` já pega todos os números, e em seguida há o `\)` para o fechamento dos parênteses, então `.*` não vai pegar nenhum caractere, e não faz diferença neste caso (só faria se a string original tivesse mais coisas entre o número e o parênteses de fechamento).

Um detalhe é que os métodos `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, etc, e o próprio `toLocaleString()` retornam os valores numéricos da data levando-se em conta o fuso-horário do browser (que por sua vez, *geralmente* usa o que está configurado no sistema operacional). Isso pode ser mudado passando-se o timezone como parâmetro:

```js
let data = "/Date(1566322265000)/";
let m = data.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
if (m) {
    let d = new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
    console.log(d.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'UTC' })); // 20/08/2019 17:31:05
    console.log(d.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' })); // 20/08/2019 14:31:05
    console.log(d.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' })); // 21/08/2019 02:31:05
}
```

Repare que tanto o dia quanto o horário podem mudar, de acordo com o fuso horário escolhido.

Já usando os *getters*, não é possível converter para qualquer timezone. Só é possível obter os valores correspondentes em UTC, usando-se os métodos [`getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth), [`getUTCDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate), etc.

---

Outro detalhe é que a [documentação de `toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Example:_Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) diz o seguinte:

> *Most of the time, the formatting returned by `toLocaleString()` is consistent. However, this might change in the future and isn't guaranteed for all languages — output variations are by design and allowed by the specification. Most notably, the IE and Edge browsers insert bidirectional control characters around dates, so the output text will flow properly when concatenated with other text.*

Em tradução livre (ênfase minha):

> Na maior parte das vezes, o formato retornado for `toLocaleString()` é consistente. Entretanto, **ele pode mudar no futuro e não é garantido para todos os idiomas** - variações no resultado são permitidas pela especificação. A mais notável são os browsers IE e Edge, que inserem caracteres de controle bidirecional em volta das datas, para que o texto possa seguir o fluxo correto quando for concatenado com outro texto.

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813272) também há uma citação a respeito:

> *... browsers are allowed a large amount of leeway with what formats they support and what characters compose the format.
>
>   ... you cannot expect to be able to compare the results of `toLocaleString` across browsers or even expect the same browser to continue giving the same result from release to release.*

Em tradução livre:

> ... é permitido aos browsers uma grande variação quanto aos formatos suportados e quais caracteres podem compor o formato.
>   ... você não pode esperar que a comparação dos resultados de `toLocaleString` entre diferentes browsers funcione, ou que o mesmo browser continue dando os mesmos resultados de uma versão para outra.

Ou seja, não é garantido que `toLocaleString()` sempre retorne o mesmo formato 100% das vezes (embora muitos *locales* aparentemente sejam estáveis nesse sentido). Então se quiser sempre o mesmo formato, independente das configurações do *locale* ou do browser, prefira a [resposta do Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408537/112052).

Comment: Aonde você leu isso: `Mas suponha que um cliente está acessando seu sistema em um computador em outro país, que não necessariamente terá suporte ao idioma português.` porque não é isso que diz a documentação?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu já fiz testes em uma máquina que só tinha um locale instalado e o browser não reconhecia os outros (ao usar pt-BR, por exemplo, ele ignorava e usava o default da máquina) e só depois de instalar os locales passou a funcionar. Então não é garantido que todas as máquinas sempre terão todos os locales, e portanto usar um formato que depende do locale não garante que o formato será sempre o mesmo

Comment: Eu vi na documentação que isso foi solucionado, porque antigamente era implementação que resolvi e agora é a API que faz o papel. Se fosse assim como você diz o formato diversos não funcionaria eu já testei outros e funciona como deveria ... Bom eu to aqui informando não é nada contra e sim uma constatação apesar que Javascript é linguagem de maluco.

Comment: Um outro fator que o valor numérico gerado ele também tem um fator local ... de tempo principalmente. não é garantido então se isso sair fora nem fazendo da maneira como você disse sobre a resposta do Felipe. Só é garantido se for tudo na mesma locale então.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Hmm, acho que preciso estudar mais a especificação (será que a máquina que eu testei é uma rara exceção?). De qualquer forma, removi este trecho por enquanto. Quanto à questão do fuso horário, acrescentei isso na resposta, obrigado! :-)

Comment: Na verdade eu fiquei curioso e realmente também estou procurando mais documentos não é nada contra a sua resposta é mesmo uma pergunta.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Tranquilo, seu comentário foi útil para eu rever essa questão dos locales. Há um tempo atrás eu li a documentação e entendi uma coisa, mas hj depois que vc comentou eu reli e entendi outra, então acho que vou ter que estudar com mais calma. Se for o caso eu atualizo a resposta depois, obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Bom dia ! @hkotsubo suas explicações foram enriquecedoras ! vejo que é uma assunto apmplo ! Gostei muito ! Obrigado !

Comment: @hard123 Pois é, datas são mais complicadas do que parecem, e as implementações das linguagens conseguem complicar ainda mais :-)