# Somar 1 dia a uma data

Tags: javascript, data

Eu preciso pegar o próximo dia depois de hoje. 
Para fazer isso eu estava tentando:

```
var data = new Date() ;
var dia = data.getDate();
dia = data.setDate(dia + 1);
```

Só que o final do retorno é **1585748377830** por exemplo.

```
if (dia < 10) {
    dia = '0' + dia;
}

var mes = data.getMonth();
if (mes < 10) {
    mes = '0' + (mes + 1);
}

var ano = data.getFullYear();
var data_string = ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;
```

O problema é que eu preciso tratar em forma de `string` essa data, então não posso apenas somar 1, já que se for no último dia do mês ele volta pro mês atual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No seu caso, não precisa atribuir o retorno de `setDate` à variável:

```js
let data = new Date();
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);
console.log(data);
console.log(data.getDate());
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Return_value), o retorno de `setDate` é "a quantidade de milissegundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970, às 00:00 em UTC" (mais conhecido como [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052)). Mas você não precisa desse número, então pode ignorá-lo. Basta chamar `setDate()` que ele já atualiza a `data`.

Inclusive o problema que você citou sobre o último dia do mês não procede, pois ao somar 1 no dia ele já atualiza o mês também:

```js
let data = new Date(2020, 0, 31); // 31 de janeiro
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);
console.log(data); // 1 de fevereiro
```

Lembrando que no exemplo acima usei `0` para o mês porque em JavaScript [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

---

Aí, para formatar, use os *getters* para obter os valores dos campos (depois de somar 1 dia à data):

```
let data = new Date();
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);

let dia = data.getDate();
let mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
let ano = data.getFullYear();
// formate a data usando os valores acima
```

Repare que já somei 1 ao mês para obter o valor correto. Isso porque no seu código tinha um problema:

```
if (mes < 10) {
    mes = '0' + (mes + 1);
}
```

Se o mês for `9`, o resultado acaba sendo `010`. Já se você somar 1 logo ao obter o valor, esse problema não ocorre, e aí basta fazer:

```
let mes = data.getMonth() + 1;
if (mes < 10) {
    mes = '0' + mes;
}
```

Comment: Ok muito obrigado cara, deu certo aqui
Agradeço muito

Comment: Sobre a formatação específica que vc está tentando fazer, tem mais detalhes aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295929/112052

Answer (score 7):

Para pegar o dia correto é só chamar o `getDate` de novo, dá uma olhada:

```js
var data = new Date();
var dia = data.getDate();
data.setDate(dia + 1);
console.log (data.getDate());
```