# Somar data em um campo de formulário

Tags: javascript, formulário, data, soma

Preciso obter a soma da data a partir do número inteiro indicado no campo do formulário, e exibi-la no segundo campo de data em um formulário de processos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei o seguinte:

```
var dias = Form.fields("DIAS").value();
var dataAtual = new Date();

Form.fields("DATA").value(dataAtual.getDate() + dias);

Form.apply();
```

Porém o resultado obtido é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a função correta para obter o valor do primeiro campo e somá-lo a data e exibir no segundo campo?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Essa pode também ser útil: [Somar 1 dia a uma data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439081/somar-1-dia-a-uma-data?rq=1)